# How do I split different versions of date patterns with Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, date, split

I've seen some examples on matching SPECIFIC date patterns, but I need to split any form of patterns possible (including the non-date characters). How can I achieve this in REGEX?

**Example(s):**

```
1. yMdhms -> (y, M, d, h, m, s)
2. yyyMMddhhmmss -> (yyy, MM, dd, hh, mm, ss)
3. yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss -> (yyy,-,mm,-,dd, ,hh,:,mm,:,ss)
```

I've used patterns such as ([a-zA-Z])(\1+) and ([a-zA-Z]+) but it doesn't give me expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with :

```
(\w)(\1)*
```

It matches any word character, and the following identical characters.

If it's any type of character, not only word characters, do with :

```
(.)(\1)*
```